# DDD и справочные таблицы

Tags: c#, база-данных, ddd

**Исходные условия:**

Есть модель велосипеда, обладающая рядом фиксированных параметров. Кроме исходных параметров модели должна быть возможность вручную добавлять новые параметры модели.

**Ситуация:**

Каждый параметр в базе данных представлен следующими характеристиками:

- Название параметра
- Единицы измерения
- Значение параметра

В базе данных существует несколько справочных таблиц (Lookup Table). В каждой из таких таблиц представлены доступные единицы измерения.

В других справочных таблицах представлены названия параметров.

На экран для каждой модели должно выводиться название параметра, его значение и единицы измерения.

**Вопросы:**

Как лучше реализовать подобный подход на основе DDD? Не хочу усложнять модель предметной области, перетаскивая в нее подход, используемый в Базе данных, которая вообще не должна влиять на модель.

**Примечания:**

Изначально до ознакомления с базой данных я считал, что параметры в модели должны быть представлены набором свойств, например:

```
    // Модель велосипеда
public class BikeModel {
    public BikeModel(string name, double height, double width) {
        ChangeName(name);
        ChangeHeight(height);
        ChangeWidth(width);
    }


    // Название модели велосипеда
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Длина велосипеда
    public double Height { get; private set; }

    // Ширина велосипеда
    public double Width { get; private }


    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void ChangeHeight(double height) {
        Height = height;
    }

    public void ChangeWidth(double width) {
        Width = width;
    }
}
```

Однако ознакомившись с базой данных я понял, что под значением "Параметр" скрывается ряд характеристик, представленных в разделе "Ситуация". Получается, что параметр можно представить Generic-классом.

```
public class ParameterOfModel<T> {
    public ParameterOfModel(string name, T value, string units) {
        SetName(name);
        SetValue(value);
        SetUnits(units);
    }

    // Название параметра
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Значение параметра
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    // Единицы измерения параметра
    public string Units { get; private set; }


    public void SetName(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void SetValue(T value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void SetUnits(string units) {
        Units = units;
    }
}
```

В таком случае модель велосипеда примет следующий вид:

```
    // Модель велосипеда
public class BikeModel {
    public BikeModel(string name, double height, double width) {
        ChangeName(name);
        ChangeHeight(height);
        ChangeWidth(width);

        AdditionalNumericParams = new List<ParameterOfModel<double>>();
    }


    // Название модели велосипеда
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Длина велосипеда
    public ParameterOfModel<double> Height { get; private set; }

    // Ширина велосипеда
    public ParameterOfModel<double> Width { get; private set; }

    // Дополнительные числовые параметры
    public List<ParameterOfModel<double>> AdditionalNumericParams { get; private set; }


    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void ChangeHeight(double height) {
        Height = new ParameterOfModel<double>("Высота велосипеда", height, "Сантиметры");
    }

    public void ChangeWidth(double width) {
        Width = new ParameterOfModel<double>("Ширина велосипеда", width, "Сантиметры");
    }

    // Добавить в модель дополнительный параметр
    public void AddNewNumericParam(ParameterOfModel<double> additionalParameter) {
        AdditionalNumericParams.Add(additionalParameter);
    }
}
```

**Но как собирать такой параметр, используя справочные таблицы?**

Comment: Есть 2 варианта: 1) - хранить значения параметров виде сроки, типы данных параметров - отдельным столбцом. 2) - для каждого типа данных делать свою таблицу значений - типа DoubleValues, StringValues, IntValues... etc

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема в том, что базу данных я изменять не могу. 
Мне интересна реализация в программном коде исходя из условий хранения в базе данных.

Comment: Программный код, по идее, должен опираться на варианты использования. Если вам надо только показать значения на экране - тем смысла в типизации, храните все в строках. Если надо максимально гибкий механизм - не должно быть никаких зашитых строк типа "Сантиметры", а типы данных и названия полей должны браться из внешних источников (БД, сервисы, конфиг файлы). Также надо бы подумать, как юзер будет вводить данные - как вы их валидировать будете? Какой параметр обязательный для велосипеда? Какой обязательно должен содержать значение (не может быть пустым)? Какие параметры не могут повторяться?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не понимаю: как можно сконфигурировать модель велосипеда. 
Валидация параметров проводится в методах-установщиках, например в ChangeWidth. Просто в данном коде они не представлены. 
Если использовать для создания модели фабрики, в которых будут использованы службы, то как можно четко указать: какие, например единицы измерения использовать, если их значение заранее известно.
Я понимаю, что тип параметра, единицы измерения и значение должны быть получены из внешнего источника. Но по условию задания заранее определен набор параметров модели велосипеда.

Comment: Если набор параметров заранее определен, зачем делать все так гибко? Сделайте нужные поля у велосипеда и все дела. По поводу созданий - мне сложно что то советовать, давно не практиковал DDD.

Comment: Дело в том, что помимо заранее определенных параметров в модели должна быть предусмотрена возможность добавления новых параметров. В самой же программе должно быть окно для вывода числовых параметров в таблицу со столбцами типа: Название параметра, значение, тип

Comment: Тогда мне не ясна проблема. Зачем тут DDD? Тут будет какая то сложная логика? Если нет, то просто делайте репозиторий, там считывайте данные из БД и стройте модель велосипеда

Comment: DDD применен ко всему проекту в целом. Модель велосипеда - только малая часть проекта. Модель как агрегат через id привязывается к конкретному экземпляру велосипеда. У модели велосипеда свои правила проверки параметров. Кроме того, некоторые параметры модели велосипеда не могут быть изменены, если модель присвоена конкретному экземпляру велосипеда. Модель не анемичная. Поэтому применение DDD я посчитал логичным. 
Вопрос касался параметров модели, использование в базе данных справочных таблиц и вызвал вопрос.

Comment: В таком случае поставлю плюсик, может кто из адептов подскажет :)

Comment: Большое спасибо) 
Немного поясню, было искушение отказаться от DDD и использовать CRUD путем обычных запросов. Это бы упростило разработку, но сам код было бы тяжело читать. Мне знакома одна система, в которой не было классов, отражающих предметную область. Там был сплошной DataRow, а логика была вмонтирована в интерфейс.
Прочитав книгу Вон Вернона по DDD, мне понравилась идея, заключающаяся в том, что модель представления приложения обращается к сервисам Прикладного уровня, который в свою очередь является клиентом доменной модели. От CRUD не отказываюсь - он при заполнении модели в сервисе)